# Style sheet is not getting linked while using EJS

Tags: css, node.js, ejs

I am learning to use ejs, express, node js. I am having probling my style sheet to my header here is my code and here is a [image: screenshot of my code]. I am using header and footer as include. Here is my [image: header.ejs]

My app.js-

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("home");
});
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: At `header.ejs` file close your `</head>` tag after link to the `CSS` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things to note here

**style.css** is an external css file. So you dont need style tags inside that file. It should only contain the css.

In your express app, you have to mention the public directory from which you are serving the static files. Like css/js/image

it can be done by

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

assuming you put the css files in public folder from in your app root. now you have to refer to the css files in your tamplate files, like

`<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
Here i assume you have put the css file in css folder inside your public folder.

So folder structure would be

```
.
./app.js
./public
    /css
        /style.css
```

**close head tag appropriately**